# WSO2API Manager : Api Store Error: Error in getting new access token

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have updated WSO2 default SLL with  the custom SSL certificate  on my Production Server on which WSO2Api installed.

SSL issues have been fixed, but now I am getting error while re-generating access token

[image]

Logs

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.APIKeyMgtException: Error in getting new accessToken
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.renewAccessToken(APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.java:281)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 500
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.service.APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.renewAccessToken(APIKeyMgtSubscriberService.java:252)
... 45 more
 TID: [0] [AM] [2014-08-27 10:57:41,440] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error in getting new      accessToken {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
```

Comment: have you done any port offset?

Comment: No..not done any port offset

Comment: why do I need to set offset? What this error means? Can you please explain this error?

Comment: Is this a single node setup or distributed setup? can you provide full error stack?

Comment: Can you please try to disable "Host name verification" as mentioned here: http://cnapagoda.blogspot.com/2014/08/host-name-verification-failed-for.html

Answer (score 1):

If APIManager runs with a port offset,you need to do addtional changes.

Change the endpoint ports defined in default APIs shipped with APIManager
Find all default APIs of the API Manager in /repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api folder. Those are Authorize API, Login API, Token API and Revoke API. Open each of them and change the address endpoint config included port value to match with offset value.The default address endpoint config is
 "address uri="https://192.168.1.7:9443/oauth2/token".If the AM standalone pack running with port offset 2 change that config as 
address uri="https://192.168.1.7:9445/oauth2/token"

Answer (score 1):

What I did to fix the issue was to 1) add admin user inside ApiKeyValidaor in api-manager.xml also into admin user via management console and into user-mgt.xml; 2) Inside api-manager.xml:

Change the following:

https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}/services/

to:
                https://[FQDN_OF_HOST}:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}/services/

Reason is my server certificate only recorded the domain name, not ip address.

My setup: Product: WSO2 AM 1.10.0 DB: MSSQL Security: SAML2 integrated with PingIdentity OS: Linux

Please also refer to this question:
[wso2 am 1.10.0 API Store: "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey" with " Invalid credentials provided."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255418/wso2-am-1-10-0-api-store-error-occurred-while-executing-the-action-generateapp/38258560#38258560)

Answer (score 0):

The error may be due to one of these two things:

1. Your admin password is not set for `ApiKeyManager` in **api_manager.xml**.
2. SSL is not set properly.