# Why does WSO2 API Manager throw an error when trying to publish an API after setting up a new jks

Tags: authentication, ssl, wso2-api-manager, jks

We had a working all-in-one instance of WSO2AM-2.1.0 running on our test servers. we wanted to test accessing the instance over https using our internal certificates. I've added our cert and key files into the wso2carbon.jks  overwriting the default wso2carbon alias [1]. I've set all instances of ${carbon.local.ip} to our hostname[2].

WSO2 can now be accessed with our hostname https://"hostname"/store/ or https://"hostname"/publisher/. 
I can log in using the admin account over https both on the publisher and store pages.

However, when I try to publish an API the following error is reported on the GUI;

> Gateway Failures 
>   Failed to Publish Environments 
>   Production and Sandbox 
>   Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Access Denied. >Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.

Logs  included for more detail

```
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,754] DEBUG - TransportUtils createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (application/soap+xml)
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,755] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter end writeTo()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,762]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2017-06-08 14:43:45,762+0100] from IP address livbodcsodev.bodc.me
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,762] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType from the OMOutputFormat =application/soap+xml
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,763] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType returned =application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="urn:loginResponse"
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,763] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter start writeTo()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,763] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   preserve=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,763] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isOptimized=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,763] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isDoingSWA=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,767] TRACE - HTTPSender Handling response - 200
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,767] DEBUG - TransportUtils createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (application/soap+xml)
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,767] TRACE - CommonsHTTPTransportSender cleanup() releasing connection for org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@5cf1d792
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,768] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter end writeTo()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,768] DEBUG - CommonsHTTPTransportSender SOAP Action from messageContext : (urn:getApi)
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,768] TRACE - AbstractHTTPSender Making new ConnectionManager
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,768] TRACE - HTTPSender Thread[http-nio-9443-exec-24,5,main] PostMethod org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@478d7879 / org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient@744b57ac
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,769] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType from the OMOutputFormat =application/soap+xml
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,769] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType returned =application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="urn:getApi"
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,770] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter start writeTo()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,770] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   preserve=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,770] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isOptimized=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,771] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isDoingSWA=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,773] DEBUG - TransportUtils Found RequestResponseTransport returning isResponseWritten()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,773] DEBUG - AxisServlet Response not written. Setting response contentType to text/xml; charset=UTF-8
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,773] DEBUG - TransportUtils Entering deleteAttachments()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,774] DEBUG - TransportUtils Exiting deleteAttachments()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,800] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter end writeTo()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,805] DEBUG - AxisServlet
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.getServletContext(GenericServlet.java:123)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.createMessageContext(AxisServlet.java:715)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.createMessageContext(AxisServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:138)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,807] DEBUG - TransportUtils createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (application/soap+xml)
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,816]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2017-06-08 14:43:45,816+0100] from IP address 192.171.134.183
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,816]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2017-06-08 14:43:45,0816] from IP address 192.171.134.183 while trying to authenticate access to service APIGatewayAdmin
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,817] DEBUG - AxisServlet org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,817] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType from the OMOutputFormat =application/soap+xml
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,818] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType returned =application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/fault"
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,818] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter start writeTo()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,818] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   preserve=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,818] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isOptimized=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,818] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isDoingSWA=false
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,823] TRACE - HTTPSender Handling response - 500
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,823] DEBUG - TransportUtils createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (application/soap+xml)
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,824] TRACE - CommonsHTTPTransportSender cleanup() releasing connection for org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@478d7879
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,825] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter end writeTo()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,827] DEBUG - TransportUtils Entering deleteAttachments()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,827] DEBUG - TransportUtils Exiting deleteAttachments()
[2017-06-08 14:43:45,828] ERROR - APIGatewayManager Error occurred when check api is published on gatewayProduction and Sandbox
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.getApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.isAPIPublished(APIGatewayManager.java:453)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateApiArtifact(APIProviderImpl.java:1015)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPIforStateChange(APIProviderImpl.java:1421)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPIforStateChange(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:36)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3755)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    ... more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.stub.APIGatewayAdminStub.getApi(APIGatewayAdminStub.java:7012)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.getApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:145)
    ... 88 more
[2017-06-08 14:43:46,022] ERROR - APIExecutor Failed to publish service gateway while executing APIExecutor.
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.FaultGatewaysException
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPIforStateChange(APIProviderImpl.java:1441)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.updateAPIforStateChange(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:36)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3755)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    ... more
[2017-06-08 14:43:46,026] ERROR - DefaultLifeCycle org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided."},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
[2017-06-08 14:43:46,040] ERROR - GovernanceArtifactImpl Invoking lifecycle action "Publish" failed. Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided."},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Execution failed for action : Publish Embedded error : FaultGatewaysException:{"PUBLISHED":{"Production and Sandbox":"Error while obtaining API information from gateway. Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided."},"UNPUBLISHED":{}}
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:482)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:338)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
    at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3755)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
    at 
    ... more
```

from the Store, I cannot access the applications list, not even the default, as a javascript error is thrown.

> DataTables warning: table id = applicationa-table - Ajax error. ... please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Looking in the logs I feel the store error is most likly related.

```
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,258]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2017-06-08 15:42:35,258+0100] from IP address 192.171.134.183
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,258]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2017-06-08 15:42:35,0258] from IP address 192.171.134.183 while trying to authenticate access to service APIKeyMgtSubscriberService
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,259] DEBUG - AxisServlet org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,259] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType from the OMOutputFormat =application/soap+xml
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,259] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter contentType returned =application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="urn:retrieveOAuthApplicationAPIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIKeyMgtException"
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,259] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter start writeTo()
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,259] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   preserve=false
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,259] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isOptimized=false
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,260] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter   isDoingSWA=false
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,260] TRACE - HTTPSender Handling response - 500
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,260] DEBUG - TransportUtils createSOAPEnvelope using Builder (class org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder) selected from type (application/soap+xml)
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,261] TRACE - CommonsHTTPTransportSender cleanup() releasing connection for org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod@609e8941
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,261] DEBUG - SOAPMessageFormatter end writeTo()
[2017-06-08 15:42:35,261] ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : QVS1jWX5fMw6z3baM8VZIWmxDysa
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
```

I've check the database, the key it mentions is in the corresponding table.

The system is deployed on a Centos 6.3 vm running openJDK 1.8, with a networked Oracle database holding the core tables (wso2_CARBON_DB and WSO2AM_DB).

Any help would be most gratefully received 
[1] https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-import-an-existing-ssl-certificate-and-private-key

[2] [wso2 am 1.10.0 API Store: "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey" with " Invalid credentials provided."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255418/wso2-am-1-10-0-api-store-error-occurred-while-executing-the-action-generateapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have almost got this to work (last 5% is issues with reserve proxy).

In `'[AM_HOME]/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml'` change to the `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol` protocol for SSL traffic (port 443)

this requires the following added to the file;

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

and the connector updated to include;

```
SSLCertificateFile="/etc/httpd/ssl/file.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile="/etc/httpd/ssl/file.key"
SSLCACertificateFile="/etc/httpd/ssl/ca.crt"
SSLCertificateChainFile="/etc/httpd/ssl/chain.pem"
SSLVerifyClient="optional"
```

---

Add the certificates to the trusted-client.jks

---

configure the `<HostName> and <MgtHostName>` in `'[AM_HOME]/repository/conf/carbon.xml'`

---

configure the following variables in `'[AM_HOME]/repository/conf/api-manager.xml'`

- `<APIStore> <ServerURL>`
- `<APIGateway> <GatewayEndpoint>`
- `<AuthManager> <ServerURL>`
- `<APIKeyValidator> <ServerURL>`

---

All changes should be to the hostname detailed in the certificate.

Comment: As I cannot edit the answer, here is the link for the solutions to the '(last 5% issues with reserve proxy)' 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525809/why-does-the-wso2-api-manager-store-have-2-url-displayed-on-ui/44762392#44762392